# Lockable Resource Plugin in Jenkins is not waiting for resource

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, locking, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins Lockable Resources plugin to decide which server to be used for various build operations in my declarative pipeline. I have set up my Lockable Resources as shown in the table below:

```
Resource Name       Labels

Win_Res_1           Windows
Lx_Res_1            Linux
```

My code to get a lockable resource is as below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Lock resource") {
            steps {
                script {
                    int num = 1
                    String label = "Windows"

                    lock(label: label, quantity: num, variable: "resource_name") {
                        echo "Locked resource name is ${env.resource_name}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say a Jenkins `job-1` is running to build an application on `Windows` and it has acquired the Windows resource `Win_Res_1`. At this point I start another Jenkins `job-2` which also has to do a build on `Windows` machine. So the expectation here is that the `job-2` will wait for the resource until `job-1` relinquishes it. Once `job-1` completes, the resource `Win_Res_1` will be available to `job-2`.

For my case this is not happening. Instead of waiting for the resource, Lockable resource plugin is throwing following error (in `job-2` while `job-1` is in progress):

`No such property: resource_name for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Is this a known limitation of the plugin?

I'm on Jenkins ver 2.89.1 and the Lockable resource plugin version is 2.2

Comment: Try with single quotes `variable: 'resource_name'`.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue and was resolved in Lockable plugin release 2.3 (JENKINS-34433).

However, I upgraded to Jenkins 2.235.1 and Lockable plugin release 2.8, issue is not observed now.